# Cramming tons of HTML in to one page

Tags: javascript, html

I am helping to design a HTML client for a game that I am collaborating with others on.

This client is going to need to have multiple scenes/pages like the login, the lobby, the actual game page, etc.

Normally, I would be just fine with navigating in and out of pages. However, the client needs to have a constant connection with the server via a Websocket, so therefore it cannot navigate away from the page.

---

## Option 1: Put everything in one file

Rather than having each scene in its own separate page, just cram all the HTML together.

Then, when one scene is needed, simply hide all the other scenes.

I do not think that this way is the way to go: from what I know about HTML and web practices, this is not a very smart practice.

---

## Option 2: jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Using jQuery's handy-dandy `.load` method, an external HTML file can be easily loaded into the current HTML file.

To me, this seems that this might be the best way. However, I am not very familiar with how this method acts, so I do not know if this will cause bumps in the road ahead.

---

## Option 3: ???

This is where I need help. Unless one of the two above options is the best way, what is the best option for my situation?

---

## Notes

- I am not looking for speed here; it's okay if there is some delay between loads.

Comment: @godmode I do not actually handle the backend of the server, but it is in Java (and maybe some groovy).

Comment: Check Angular JS (https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: damn, was hoping you'd use php. `<?php include('anotherPage.php'); ?>` works great

Comment: This sounds like a job for a library designed for single page apps.

Comment: in my experience $.load() really slows down a page

Comment: @godmode We might be able to incorporate something with that...

Comment: I use `$('selector').load('url', function() {});` to load another page as a pop-up into _'selector'_ in response to a button click and it performs great. Oh, and Java .jsp has `<jsp:include page="/another/file.jsp" />` which works essentially the same as `<?php include ...>`.  Neither of those would be concerns to me.

Comment: @StephenP Answers are not meant for comments.

Comment: My previous comment is definitely a comment, addressing concerns raised in godmode's comments, and is not in any way an attempt to answer the question. This comment is also a comment.

Comment: I see; I did not understand that you were responding to other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your backend but it seems like you are looking for a single page app solution.

I recommend [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), currently maintained by Google.

Comment: very true, but isn't Angular 2.0 (not yet released) not backwards compatible

Comment: @godmode actually according to their blog, they said they will work on migration scripts from v1* to 2 (http://angularjs.blogspot.se/2014/10/ng-europe-angular-13-and-beyond.html)

Comment: Google also announced that they will support v1.x until 50% of the user base has switched to v2. Take that for what you will.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a few examples using hypothetical HTML pages?

Comment: @SirPython check this out (https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned Angular, but I'll just throw out the recommendation of [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) as well. Knockout has a less steep learning curve than AngularJS, and though it doesn't have as many features as Angular does, the latest version does have better browser support.

Both Knockout and Angular have excellent documentation and tutorials available via their websites.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Angular 2. Since you seem like a beginner in front-end (correct me if I am wrong), starting with Angular 2 would be great over 1 because then you can learn this really good JS framework only once. It will help you keep everything organized and will prevent you from making your markup messy.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a few examples using (a) hypothetical HTML page(s)? Now having looked into AngularJS, I don't see how this helps.